# How to show this message when mouse stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want use python3 (tkinter) to finish this function:
When the mouse stop at some place, one message will be shown.
When the mouse move away, the message will disappear.

Is there any information for this function?

Comment: Well, you can bind to the `"<Motion>"` event to learn about motion, but you'll have to use a timer to detect when mouse motion stops.  That's not considered an "event".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This effect can be achieved by combining `bind` and `after`.

The motion of cursor is tracked with `bind` which removes `label`

`after` checks every 50 milliseconds for non-movement of cursor and uses `place` manager to display `label`.

I've updated answer since `bind` `event.x and y` caused an occasional bug in the positioning of the message. (displaying it at top left corner)

Tracked it down to `event.x event.y`, so replaced it with

`x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()`

`y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()`

This update solves the problem, now it functions as intended.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Message")
x = y = xx = yy = 0

def display(event):
    global x, y
    x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
    y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
    label.place_forget()

def check(xx, yy):
    global x, y
    if x == xx and y == yy:
        label.place(x = x, y = y, anchor = "s")
    else:
        xx, yy = x, y
    root.after(50, check, xx, yy)

root.bind("<Motion>", display)
root.after(10, check, xx, yy)
root.mainloop()
```